# jquery dialog in IE closing after 16 seconds

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, dialog, delay

We have a modal jquery dialog that works fine in browsers except my IE9. The dialog window closes with more than 15 seconds delay in all cases: confirm, cancel, close. I have an JSCompanion that doesn't show errors, everything fine.

```
$( "#"+status ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:180,
            width:400,
            modal: true,
            title: "ECO confirmation",
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function() {
                    $.ajax({
                          type: 'GET',
                          url: url,
                          success: function(){
                              $( "#"+status).dialog( "close" );   
                              $('#'+trid+'>td.status').html(status);
                              $('#'+trid+'>td:last').html('');
                          }
                    });

                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $( "#"+status  ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
```

Any ideas, insights, hints? Would be great!

Comment: Just a suggestion: try to move `$( "#"+status).dialog( "close" );` after this line `$('#'+trid+'>td:last').html('');`

Comment: I had kicked them out and it doen't make a difference. It delays closing the window in any case, click on "Cancel", "Closelink", "Confirm"

Comment: Which version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: jquery-ui-1.9.1.min.js          jquery-1.8.2.min.js

Comment: Can you provide a link? Maybe you set IE9 to IE8 browser mode?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide a link at the moment. IE9 is running in compatibility mode. I'm currently looking for a switch to switch that off...

Comment: good hint, thanks. Without the compatibility view it works fine...

Comment: I will add as an answer, so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your IE9 isn't set to IE8 browser mode.